# Formula for Riemann Zeta function as term in a series which looks like trigonometric Taylor expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta, bessel-functions, trigonometric-series

I am interested in :

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}\ \zeta{(2n)}}{(2n)!} = ???
$$

This could possibly be a Bessel function of some kind, because of the way the Riemann zeta function of even integer arguments can be defined using Bernoulli numbers and even argument factorials.

Comment: It can be reduced to $\sum_{n\geqslant1}\left[\cos\left(\frac xn\right)-1\right]=-2\sum_{n\geqslant1}\sin^2\left(\frac x{2n}\right)$. But I don't see any possible approach for those series.

Comment: There is also $\int_{|z|=1/2} \frac{e^{x/z}-1 }{e^{2i\pi z}-1}dz$

Comment: @reuns can this be evaluated in polynomial time?

Comment: polynomial time ???

Comment: Is there an numeric method or other such algorithm that can evaluate this in consistent, computationally efficient time?

Comment: http://mathwiki.cs.ut.ee/asymptotics/05_polynomial_complexity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be easily assessed that, the given sum is the expanded and simplified form of the sum, $ S=\lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^{k} (\cos \frac{x}{r}-1) $.
$S=-2\lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^{k} \sin^2 \frac{x}{2r} $.
This is a convergent series for any $ \mid x \mid < \infty $.

It can be evaluated using Euler Maclaurin series or other summation evaluation methods but a closed form solution of this sum in elementary finite number of functions, i feel, cannot be given.

Comment: is there a polynomial time method of evaluating (or at least approximating) this?

Comment: You can try Euler Maclaurin summation formula to evaluate this sum.